# Trouble running an application made with PyInstaller, importing GTK--searching nonexistent directories

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable of my Python application that uses PyGTK to make a GUI. I have a well-established, automated build process using Pyinstaller that has worked for me for a previous application. Suffice it to say that it calls the usual Makespec.py and Build.py with 32-bit Python 2.7, with Pyinstaller configured for 32 bits. The resulting 32-bit application works fine on my machine and another machine running Windows 7 64-bit, but fails on 32-bit Windows XP with this error:

```
C:\OutNav_0_64\OutNav_0.64>outnav
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\iu.py", line 436, in importHook
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\iu.py", line 521, in doimport
  File "C:\Users\462974\Documents\Local Sandbox\tools\utilities\Oni\build\pyi.win32\OutNav\outPYZ1.pyz/gtk", line 40, in
 <module>
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\iu.py", line 477, in importHook
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\iu.py", line 495, in doimport
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\iu.py", line 297, in getmod
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\archive.py", line 468, in getmod
  File "C:\Pyinstaller-1.5\iu.py", line 109, in getmod
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The strange part is, there is no C:\Pyinstaller-1.5 directory on my machine or the one experiencing the error. I have no idea why it is attempting to run code from this nonexistent directory, or what the missing DLL is. Can anyone help me fold PyGTK into my application?

NOTE: The first line of the trace, line 23 in my program, is

```
import gtk
```

UPDATE: My manager successfully ran it on 64-bit Windows XP.
UPDATE 2: He was mistaken, it was 64-bit Windows 7. It has the same problem on his Windows XP installation.

Also, on the original machine it failed on, from the directory of the executable, I did this:

```
>>> import imp
>>> fp = open('gtk._gtk.pyd', 'rb')
>>> mod = imp.load_module('gtk._gtk', fp, 'gtk._gtk.pyd', ('.pyd', 'rb', 3))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: Which version of pyinstaller are you using?  Is the executable built as a single file or a single directory?

Comment: I am using pyinstaller 1.5.1; it's built as a single directory.

Comment: I have reconstructed the call in iu.py that causes the ImportError: mod = imp.load_module('gtk._gtk', fileobj, "..\\path\\to\\gtk._gtk.pyd", ('.pyd', 'rb', 3))

Comment: Is the gtk._gtk.pyd file mentioned in the `dist` folder created by PyInstaller?   Also, does it help if you build the application on Windows XP?  http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/324 appears to be a vaguely similar issue.

Comment: gtk._gtk.pyd is located in the same directory as the executable. I don't have an XP machine of my own, so building it on XP would be difficult.

Comment: If you're using Windows 7 Pro, Ultimate or Enterprise, you can use Windows XP Mode.  Incidentally, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159846/ may be a Java question but @matt's answer does describe one case where you can get a `The specified procedure could not be found` error.

Comment: What other DLLs are being included with your application?  If you're using pyinstaller 1.5.1, are you aware that it can incorrectly copy system DLLs (in my experience, kernel32.dll, kernelbase.dll and gdiplus.dll) into the `dist` folder?  If there are some of these DLLs in your application's `dist` folder, does it help if you remove them?

Comment: I have none of those in the installation directory. See my update above: it actually doesn't run on any XP machine I've tried and I got a similar error when recreating the failing command from the interpreter. My current guess is that the gtk._gtk.pyd file created by Pyinstaller is somehow incompatible with Windows XP.

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.  I don't have access to a Windows XP machine at the moment (I'm on W7 Home Premium) so I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yeah, my workaround was to simply get remote access to an XP machine and build it there, which seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the .pyd file (which is in the format of a .DLL file) generated by pyinstaller on Windows 7 is incompatible with Windows XP. My solution was to simply recreate my build process on a Windows XP machine, which solved it to my satisfaction.