# Causes of a UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: visual-studio-2012, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a `C++` code that I compile with `Visual Studio 2012` as a `.dll`.

Then, I load that library in a Java application with the `System.loadLibrary` method.

I have done it lots of time, compiling the library with elder version on Visual Studio, without problems.

Now, compiling it with VS2012 I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\path\to\library.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
```

I checked the .dll with `Dependecy Walker` and no dependence is missing.

I really don't know what I could do so as to make it work.

Can you give me some hint?

Comment: It looks as though a symbol is missing as opposed to any issue loading the library itself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, do you know how I can identify that symbol?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159846/unsatisfiedlinkerror-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)